# database is not updating using select and update command in same try block

Tags: c#, database, string, exception, timeout

Here is my code which calls a function to update data into the database......

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Malik\Desktop\research_fields.txt");

            //var lines = new System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Malik\Desktop\research_fields.txt");
            Program p = new Program();
            var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Malik\Desktop\research_fields.txt");
            var dd = new List<Tuple<string, double, string>>();

            //string document = "The trie data structure has many properties which make it especially attractive for representing large files of data. These properties include fast retrieval time, quick unsuccessful search determination, and finding the longest match to a given identifier. The main drawback is the space requirement. In this paper the concept of trie compaction is formalized. An exact algorithm for optimal trie compaction and three algorithms for approximate trie compaction are given, and an analysis of the three algorithms is done. The analysis indicate that for actual tries, reductions of around 70 percent in the space required by the uncompacted trie can be expected. The quality of the compaction is shown to be insensitive to the number of nodes, while a more relevant parameter is the alphabet size of the key.";

            //string[] document = get_Abstract();
            //string line;
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KHIZER;Initial Catalog=subset_aminer;Integrated Security=True");

                con.Open();
                SqlCommand query = con.CreateCommand();
                query.CommandText = "select p_abstract from sub_aminer_paper where pid between 1 and 500 and DATALENGTH(p_abstract) != 0";

                SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

                string summary = null;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    summary = reader["p_abstract"].ToString();
                    dd.AddRange(lines.Select(line => Tuple.Create(line, p.calculate_CS(line, summary), summary)));

                    var top_value = dd.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (top_value != null)
                    {
                        // look up record using top_value.Item3, and then store top_value.Item1
                        var abstrct = top_value.Item3.ToString();
                        var r_field = top_value.Item1.ToString();

                        write_To_Database(abstrct, r_field);
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();

                /* System.IO.StreamWriter fileW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Malik\Desktop\write_research_fields_temp.txt");

                 foreach (var item in d.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item2))
                 {
                     fileW.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.Item2, item.Item1);
                 }

                 fileW.Close(); */
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");

            }
        }


        public static void write_To_Database(string document, string research_field)
        {
             try
             {
                 string connection = "Data Source=KHIZER;Initial Catalog=subset_aminer;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
                 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
                 {
                     con.Open();

                     string query = "select id from sub_aminer_paper where pid between 1 and 500 and DATALENGTH(p_abstract) != 0 and p_abstract LIKE @p_abstract";
                     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                     {
                         string st = document;
                         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_abstract", st);

                         int id = 0;
                         using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                         {
                             while (reader.Read())
                             {
                                 id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                             }

                             reader.Close();

                             string update_query = "update sub_aminer_paper set research_area = @research_area where id = @id";
                             using (SqlCommand cmd_update = new SqlCommand(update_query, con))
                             {
                                 int identity = id;
                                 string r_field = research_field;

                                 cmd_update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", identity);
                                 cmd_update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@research_area", r_field);
                                 //cmd_update.CommandTimeout = 20;
                                 cmd_update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     con.Close();
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
               Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
             }
             finally
             {
               Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
             } 
        }
```

The code looks fine while debugging but in between after every execution of `cmd_update.ExecuteNonQuery();` this command in the `write_T0_Database()` method. So just a blank console screen appears for some time then displays this error "exception timeout expired the time period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding" Then displays "Executing Finally Block." then again same exception after some time then again "Executing Finally Block.".
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Because you have two finally blocks outputting the same content and will _always_ be executed, upon failure within the try/catch or not. It would appear you have (at least) two failures, at least one of each being in each of the try/catch segments. The exceptions, and their messages, are a different issue, and apparently one to do with connectivity/longevity of the commands being issued,

Comment: So what should I do @Grant Thomas

Comment: Extend the timeouts on the commands (not always ideal) or better, make the SQL return quicker.

Comment: How to extend timeouts on commands @Grant